# Simple HTML issue

Tags: html, css

Gday all

Now im quiet new to this and the following code snipet seems like a simple problem but I cant seem to fix it. The idea of "main box was to put a white background around both "main" and "mainr"

When i put the footer above the bottom div it all works fine.

I can supply the full code if it helps just didn't want to bog down the page

Thanks in advance

```
<div id = "mainbox">
<article id="main">
    <pre align="center">Mission  Statement </pre>
        <p align="center">Mission  Ready </p>
</article>
<article id="mainr">
    <pre align="center">Mission  Statement </pre>
        <p align="center">Mission Ready</p>
</article>
</div>
<footer id="footer">Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</footer>
```

Comment: use `style="background-color:white"`

Comment: You should post your CSS too so we can see how it's styled.

Comment: So what exactly your question is?

Answer (score 0):

just add in your css

```
#mainr , #main
{
   background-color : white;
}
this above code apply to all object whose id is either "main" or "mainr".
```

or

```
article
{
  background-color : white;  /*This will apply to all article HTML tag*/
}
```

or you can define cssclass and give to the HTML object like

```
.bcgrnwhite  /*give class name , you can give anything but good to remember quickly */
{
   background-color : white; /*you can give other properties which you apply as common*/
}

<div id = "mainbox">
<article id="main" class="bcgrnwhite">   /*here I change, given css*/
    <pre align="center">Mission  Statement </pre>
        <p align="center">Mission  Ready </p>
</article>
<article id="mainr" class="bcgrnwhite">   /*here I change, given css*/
    <pre align="center">Mission  Statement </pre>
        <p align="center">Mission Ready</p>
</article>
</div>
<footer id="footer">Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</footer>
```

"." is used for general class.

"#" is used for id related css. 
h1, p1, table is used to apply for all h1 , p1 or table tag in html.

you just learn more about [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) , http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Its all so bad to style on ID´s - just dont!

Comment: @SimonPertersen How so?

Comment: @Tieson T. styling everything with IDs, you are losing out on the benefits of classes. Fx building styling api's which is great!

Comment: @SimonPertersen So you assume you have to use one or the other? Can you cite a canonical resource for why using ID selectors are "so bad"?

Comment: I cannot come up with anything that would be benefits to style on ID's  all the benefits you have of classes just goes away. 
You can style on id's but when you expand your project, or going to restructure it, it's going to hurt yourself. Its bad for structure, There are reasons why all great frameworks are build on classes and not id's. I started of styling on id's but learn really quickly why  it took much more time to fix issues when the structure changes. ID's is great for javascript cause it makes calls faster. http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2

Comment: Just to extend that its a great way to separate css and javascript so that javascript runs on ID's and css on classes. So all in all if you got a reason why you should please feel free to share. @TiesonT.